# in MYSQL, get only those columns that have values that are the same

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table showing what pieces of a puzzle a user has in Boolean  like...

```
client   |  col A | col B | col C | col D | col E
john Doe |    1   |   1   |   0   |   0   |   1
Jane Deer|    0   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0
```

And I can grab the row from the Db.

```
// Get puzzle pieces
$requery = "SELECT * FROM puzzletbl WHERE client_id = '$client_id' LIMIT 1";
$reresult = mysqli_query($dbc, $requery);

// Check for missing pieces
if ($reresult){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $status = array("NO", "OKAY");

    } // END WHILE
} // END  IF REresult
```

I need to get only those columns with 0 (they are missing piece) so I can  add that to an email letting them know what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through `$row`, and test whether the value is `0`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($reresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $zero_cols = array();
    foreach ($row as $col => $val) {
        if ($col == "client") {
            $client = $val;
        } elseif ($val == 0) {
            $zero_cols[] = $col;
        }
    }
    // Send mail to $client with $zero_cols info
}
```